# Powershell: Convert string with/without leading numbers to integer

Tags: string, powershell, integer

I am looking for the smartest way to convert a string with leading numbers into an integer value. It should use only the leading numbers in front of a text-string or 0 if there is no leading number.
Currently I am using this code-snippet, but I hope there is a better way:

```
[int][regex]::Match('123test456','^\d*').value
```

Comment: Regex is perfectlly Fine for this Kind of topics

Comment: Personally, I would use `-replace` —> `[int]('123hih456' -replace '\D.*')`

Comment: @AdminOfThings I think this is the shortest and fastes solution.

Answer (score 0):

Or this.  The automatic $matches hashtable variable has the answer if a match is found.

```
if ('123test456' -match '^\d*') { $matches[0] }

123
```

Comment: @zett42 Good point.  I made it an if statement instead.

Comment: that needs an [int] conversation to handle the situation if the string has no leading numbers.